# Scaling argument for the heat equation in a bounded domain

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

We want to study the long time behavior of the heat equation $u_t - u_{xx} = 0$ in the domain $[-1,1]$. Now consider the rescaling $u^{\epsilon} =  u(x/\epsilon, t/\epsilon^2)$. Then 
$u^\epsilon$ solves 
$$u^\epsilon_{t} - u^{\epsilon}_{xx} = 0 \quad \text{ in } [-\epsilon,\epsilon].$$
When $\epsilon \to 0$ we are considering the long time asymptotic behavior of $u$. What happens to the domain? Why does it shrink to $\{0\}$?

Comment: As $x$ ranges from $0$ to $\epsilon$, $x/\epsilon$ ranges from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question correctly. The domain shrinks since you rescale it to shrink. Could you elaborate on what precisely your point is?

Comment: you want to reach the large-$t$ asymptotic for $u$ in a short time for $u^\epsilon$, keeping the heat diffusion constant the same for $u$ and $u^\epsilon$; so heat will only spread out over small distances for $u^\epsilon$, and to cover the entire domain it will have to be shorter than the domain for $u$.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Thanks. I'm confused because when you pass to the limit $\epsilon \to 0$ the domain seems to be reduced to a point. Also, I wonder what kind of scaling would we need to do to get large times and also enlarge the domain so it becomes $\mathbb R$ in the limit.

Comment: If you wish to reach the infinite real axis in a finite rescaled time, you will have to also rescale the diffusion constant (which was omitted from the heat equation).

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Could you elaborate on what you mean in an answer? Actually, what I'd like to do is consider both $t \to \infty$ and get to an infinite domain (and time should be faster).

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the heat equation with a diffusion constant $D$,
$$u_t - D u_{xx} = 0,\;\;0<x<L,$$
rescale length and time as $x'=x/\lambda$, $t'=t/\tau$, $D'=D\tau/\lambda^2$, to obtain the dimensionless equation
$$u_{t'} - D' u_{x'x'} = 0,\;\;0<x'<L/\lambda.$$
So if you wish the domain in $x'$ to scale to infinity and infinite time $t$ to be reached in finite rescaled time $t'$, you need to take the limit $\lambda\rightarrow 0$, $\tau\rightarrow\infty$. In that limit $D'\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Thank you. Mathematically, how do you justify rescaling $D$ if it is a constant?

Comment: there is nothing to justify; $D$ is a constant in units of $cm^2/s$; $D'$ is dimensionless, so it must be different from $D$, which it is.

Comment: Thanks. I see that it makes sense from the point of view of physical dimensional analysis, but I'm not sure how to think about this rescaling mathematically.